# Does the Mechanize gem support TLS 1.2 and how to set it?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, tls1.2

I want to use the Mechanize gem to do a TLS 1.2 POST request, but I have poor knowledge into SSL and TLS, so I can't seem to find any useful way to determine if I set it correctly. `Mechanize.new.ssl_version` yields `nil`

Answer (score 0):

`Mechanize.new.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2` works. It was just my POST body that was erroring.

Drew inspiration from here https://crftr.com/yes-ruby-1-9-can-support-tls-1-2/ in determining if my OS SSL configuration was good.

And used TLS enforcing sites shared here https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/127984/what-website-accepts-only-tls-1-2-so-i-can-verify-client-capability to test client.